# Dc power supply help

Tags: arduino, relay

2.6 amp power supply that i have stripped my question is would it still work if i hooked my black 
(live) wire into the positive and my white(negative) wire into ground

From my understanding DC only needs the live wire since it is direct flow and the negative can be ground. This will be connected to a solid state relay.

[image: pic of my power supply]

Edit 
Forgot to add.what it.will connect to

[image]

Comment: When I rotate my head [I whip my head back and forth](https://youtu.be/ymKLymvwD2U?t=1m13s).

Comment: This question is so unclear the only answer is for you not to plug anything into anything.

Comment: To begin with, that's not a 6 amp supply.

Comment: Now that you've fixed that, are you sure that the plain black wire is positive, and white-striped is ground? It is usually (although, not always) the opposite. How did you determine the polarity?

Comment: Use a digital multi meter and find the polarity then use this information to plug it in.

Answer (score 1):

If your solid state relay PCB is made to work with 12V and does not need more current than the power supply can deliver you are good.
DC does not only need the life wire, there is always a return needed (GND in your case). As *Blair Fonville* already mentioned, you should not trust the markings on the power supply strips and check the polarity and voltage of the output.